# What's all this deploy.akamaitechnologies.com traffic?

Tags: wireshark, cms, tcpdump, pcap

I happened to do a tcpdump while leaving my Mac idle, and when I came back after a mere half-hour there were something like 5000 packets involving deploy.akamaitechnologies.com, in which my computer was asking it on port TCP 443 for something, and getting back 1448 payload bytes of something. The actual bytes look garbled, so I have no idea what is being delivered.

I'm inclined to add akamaitechnologies to my Wifi router's list of domains to block.

Anybody know what this data is?

Thanks.

Comment: "in which my computer was asking it on port TCP 443 for something, and getting back 1448 payload bytes of something. The actual bytes look garbled"  As RedGrittyBrick noted, that's HTTPS traffic, meaning it's encrypted, so it'll look random unless it's decrypted.

Comment: Yes traffic is incredible, and it also exists in GNU/linux. Also check http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/11/29/how-content-delivery-networks-cdns-work/

Answer (score 16):

[Akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) run a content distributions system used by major websites to provide fast web response on a global scale.

Port 443 is used for HTTPS - the encrypted version of HTTP web-page access.

It is quite normal to see a lot of traffic directed through Akamai.

At the time this question was asked, Apple used Akamai as their primary content delivery network.

---

Update:

> On July 21, 1999, at Macworld Expo New York, **Apple** and **Akamai**
>   announced a strategic partnership to build Apple's new media network,
>   QuickTime TV (QTV), based on QuickTime Streaming Server.[11] Both
>   companies later announced that **Apple** had made a $12.5 million
>   investment in the company the previous month.[12] **Apple** continues to
>   use **Akamai** as their **primary content delivery network**[13] for a wide
>   range of applications including software downloads from Apple's
>   Website, QuickTime movie trailers, and the iTunes Store.[14]

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies#Customers

> **Apple** (NASDAQ:AAPL) recently launched its **iCloud** service that allows
>   users to store their music, photos and other documents on the cloud.
>   This content is thus accessible from Apple’s mobile devices and any
>   PC. While this is certainly a shiny introduction from **Apple** to fuel
>   the growth in sales of its iPhone and iPad devices, it also holds
>   promise for **Akamai** (NASDAQ:AKAM). As a content delivery vendor for
>   Apple, Akamai has an advantage over its competitors

From http://www.trefis.com/stock/akam/articles/61838/does-icloud-hold-promise-for-akamai/2011-06-14

> **Akamai's** servers and Apple's datacenters are being hammered for **OS X** Lion downloads.

From http://www.zdnet.com/blog/perlow/os-x-lion-awakens-can-akamai-handle-downloads-for-apples-cloud/17901

Comment: Microsoft also uses Akamai, most recently for the Technet and MSDN release of Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: This sounds more like a wish or hope than anything. What if something nefarious is going on? After all we are in the age of warrantless wiretapping etc etc.

Comment: @Warren: See updated answer. This is a technical Q&A site. Please consider this when you phrase your follow up questions.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows,

```
netstat -o
```

shows what PID was using the port the connection is on.

In my case, it was `jusched`, the Java Update Scheduler.

You can do this in Linux and UNIX with `netstat` and `lsof` too.